# React: State update delay

Tags: json, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to change state by checking radio button. When I check it, it updates the value only after I check the next radio button. If I click first radio button it won't change the state, and if I check the second one it updates state with the previously checked radio button's value. Can anyone help me fixing this?

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = { checked: false, radioValue: '' }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        console.log("this.state", this.state); // Gets previous value

        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">

                       <input
          name="radioValue"
          type="radio"
          value="aaa"
          checked={this.state.radioValue === 'aaa'}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />First Radio Button

            <br />

        <input
          name="radioValue"
          type="radio"
          value="bbb"
          checked={this.state.radioValue === 'bbb'}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />Second Radio Button

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue - https://codepen.io/dirtyd77/pen/WWaRew

Comment: So weird! Maybe it only happens on browser?

Comment: Okay now I see the problem. In your code you were console logging "value", but right now I was trying to log "this.state" or "this.state.radioValue"

Comment: `console.log("this.state", this.state)` put you console in render before return than you will get the updated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    },()=>console.log(this.state));
```

you can also check like this by using callback in setstate

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
class App extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: ""
    };
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("this.state", this.state); // Gets previous value
    this.setState({
      checked: event.target.value
    });
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <input name="radioValue" type="radio" value="aaa"
                checked={this.state.checked === 'aaa'}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
                First Radio Button
            <br />
            <input name="radioValue" type="radio" value="bbb"
                checked={this.state.checked === 'bbb'}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
                Second Radio Button
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

It works well on my machine.